# How to show Telephone Number range

Tags: design-patterns, tables

I need to show telephone numbers which can be the range  of following fashion.
1: 123456710- 123456720(11 Numbers)
2: 234567835-234567842( 8 Numbers)
and so on

I need to represent this info in table with following columns. How do I show the range of numbers as there can be many. Should I show just count like one number range and then a badge with count and on click on this show a popup or expand the row. Any idea or suggestions?

---

**Product Name   |  Company Name   | Telephone Numbers**

---

ABC             |  XYZ            | 123456710- 123456720(11 Numbers), 234567835-234567842( 8 Numbers)...

---

MNO      |  PQR | 123456710- 123456720(11 Numbers), 234567835-234567842( 8 Numbers)...

---

EFG             |  LPN            | 123456710- 123456720(11 Numbers), 234567835-234567842( 8 Numbers)...

Comment: What are these numbers used for? Can you please describe a case how a user uses the table, and the numbers in particular?

Comment: These are telephone numbers sold to businesses. Like we sell number of Vodafone and than Vodafone sell it to retail customers. So, Vodafone can buy bulk Telephone Numbers for each area(province) in a specific country. Does it make sense now ?

Comment: Ok, so the numbers are the property of a company. But what users do with that data? Are they search for some particular number? Do they need to know at all the exact numbers? The presentation depends on users' goals. Probably, they only need to know the total amount of numbers per company?

Comment: The numbers will be searched by company's representatives. They wil check how many numbers they have. What feature is  mapped with a particular range, and their location. Like a range from 01-99 (100 Numbers) can have voice service and 101-199(100 Numbers) can have data services. Numbers can be unlimited  and it can fall into thousands.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try using a variant of [material design chips](https://material.io/components/chips/#specs) to separate the ranges, and you can use badges to show how many numbers make up each range.

Since you're dealing with phone numbers, and you have that in the column headers, you can take away the 'Numbers' repeating in each range, substituting a badge.

[image]

I tried making the numbers smaller by repeating the last 2 digits as well.

If you have more ranges than the column allows for, you can state the ranges not shown, with an 'expand' option to open the row to accomodate seeing all of them.

Comment: Thanks. I am also inline to your idea.I am opening a slider window than expanding row as in my case there can be many numbers.

Comment: Agree that a slider would work well when you have to see a large range..

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I'd recommend to use Master-Detail pattern, see the image:
[image]

In this way you have freedom to represent on the Detail level all the information, that users need. Otherwise you are limited to the table representation only, which doesn't fit your claim on having unlimited amount of data.

Comment: Thanks! In a real-life scenario there can be thousand of ranges under each category (voice, data etc).  So, I am planning to show a slider than expanding rows as it is break the UI visually. Also, worst there are 10-15 columns in the grid:(

Comment: @Hemchandra, I just hope you got the idea: master-detail pattern gives you a lot of space on the Detail level, while Master helps you to filter/search the needed records in a quick way. Don't try to place all the data on the same level/screen.